# Timepicker validation not working as required for the 5 dynamic input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, timepicker

I have used jquery timepicker to add time to the input fields. The validation for these fields is checked on the click of the "Next" button. I have written the code in javascript by forming arrays. But it seems the validation fails for the last else if condition. Kindly help. I have made this Jsfiddle for reference.
     [JSFiddle][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/arneh1Lt/32/
```

Validations required for this page are:
The start and end time entered in the second row...should not fall in the range of the start and end time entered in the first row..

Then if any of the venue values entered in the Venue field are same...and also their corresponding start and end time are same..then it should give an alert saying that.. Same time and venue are not allowed.

No alert should be displayed if the start and end time values entered in the time fields are same and their corresponding venues are different.

Comment: Do you mean, you are checking event start time and end time is not equal ?

Comment: I want to check that..if the start time and end time in the first row and in the second row are equal...and if the venue in the first and second row are same..then it give an alert saying that..Same time and venue not allowed...

Comment: i think Date.parse cause error select box value like "12:30am" so Date.parse return NaN

Comment: so what I use instead of Date.parse... to rectify this issue..

Comment: i will check and get back to you and one que. you can create all events for same date right? or user can create with multiple date ?

Comment: one date only..for one event..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146437/discussion-between-sagar-patel-and-unnati).